# Grandtotal is missing Tax Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, tax

In Magento 1.9.3.1 i have the following problem:

[image: Tax missing]

As you can see, tax are not included in grandtotal, but i have absolutely no idea why, because my tax settings should be alright:

[image: tax configuration]

any idea why this is not working? Thanks a lot!

Comment: what's your php version? There's some known grand total calculation bug when running magento 1 in php 7

Comment: it's php 5.6 :-(